# Monaco standalone editor throws not a function error when implementing onkeydown event

Tags: monaco-editor

I might be implementing this incorrectly but this is the code I'm using that throws the error. This is written in TypeScript. Any help on instantiating the event handler would be greatly appreciated.

```
var htmlEditor = Monaco.Editor.create(document.getElementById("codeArea"), {
        value: "Generating code...",
        mode: "text/html",
        readOnly: true
    });
    htmlEditor.setValue(customizeMap.generateCode());
    htmlEditor.updateOptions({ readOnly: true });
    htmlEditor.onKeyDown((ev: KeyboardEvent) =>
    {
        if (ev.keyCode === KeyCodes.Escape)
        {
            Alert("escape key selected");
        }
        else if (ev.keyCode === KeyCodes.Tab)
        {
            Alert("tab key selected");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing (first line) `Monaco.Editor.create` with `monaco.editor.create` and `if (ev.keyCode === KeyCodes.Escape) { Alert("escape key selected"); }` with `if (ev.keyCode === monaco.KeyCode.Escape) { alert("escape key selected"); }` - you see casing if off and KeyCodes vs. KeyCode etc.. Check the spelling and casing :)